# Copy all files from directory to another with Grunt.js copy

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to copy all the files in a directory to another directory as part of my build process. It works fine for individual files that I specify explicitly but when I try to copy the whole directory it does weird things like copies the full directory structure (or nothing at all). Here is the relevant part from my GruntFile.js:

```
copy: {
  myvoice: {
    files: [
      { src:"src/html/index.html", dest:"dist/myvoice/index.html" },
      { src:"src/html/css/style.css", dest:"dist/myvoice/css/style.css" },
      { src:"src/html/js/require.js", dest:"dist/myvoice/js/require.js" },
      { src:"build/myvoice/main.js", dest:"dist/myvoice/js/main.js" },
      { src:"src/html/css/fonts/*", dest:"dist/myvoice/css/fonts/" }
    ]
  }
},
```

Specifically it's the last line that I can't get to work:

```
      { src:"src/html/css/fonts/*", dest:"dist/myvoice/css/fonts/" }
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The `flatten: true` option as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18991208/108348) might work for some cases, but it seems to me that the more common requirement (as in my case) is to copy a folder and its sub-folder structure, as-is, to `dest`. It seems that in most cases if you have sub-folders, they are probably being referenced that way in code.  The key to doing this is the `cwd` option, which will preserve folder structure relative to the specified working directory:

```
copy: {
  files: {
    cwd: 'path/to/files',  // set working folder / root to copy
    src: '**/*',           // copy all files and subfolders
    dest: 'dist/files',    // destination folder
    expand: true           // required when using cwd
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- you're right this answer is more what I was looking for when I asked the question. I'd learned to deal the the flattening caused by the previous answer but it was annoying.

Comment: I have lost over an hour for this... If you use `cwd` options, be sure to turn `expand:true`. If you don't set `expand:true`, cwd will not work properly.

Comment: I had to make sure directory paths end with '/' and add `flatten: false` to get this working.

Comment: `**/*`

Thats what I was looking for I was using ** thanks man.

Answer (score 46):

This task will maintain folder structure if you specify a file glob. What you want is the `flatten` option which will remove the structure.

```
{
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    src: ['src/html/css/fonts/**'],
    dest: 'dist/myvoice/css/fonts/',
    filter: 'isFile'
}
```

Find the rest of the available options in the [Github repo](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 26):

I would like to add that changing the format of the [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) in *src* will modify how the copy works.

As pointed out by *bmoeskau* above, the following will copy **everything** inside `dist/` and move it to `path/to/dir` (overwriting the destination if it already exists).

```
copy: {
  files: {
    expand: true,
    dest: 'path/to/dir',
    cwd: 'dist/',
    src: '**'
  }
}
```

Note however, that:

```
copy: {
  files: {
    expand: true,
    dest: 'path/to/dir',
    cwd: 'dist/',
    src: '*'
  }
}
```

Will only copy files inside `dist/` as well as directories, but will **not** copy the contents of those directories to the destination.

Also, the following with `src: '*/*'` will **only** copy directories with contents inside `dist/`. That is, files just inside `dist/` will not be copied.

```
copy: {
  files: {
    expand: true,
    dest: 'path/to/dir',
    cwd: 'dist/',
    src: '*/*'
  }
}
```

Finally, same as above, but `src: '**/**'` will copy **only** files inside `dist/` as well as files inside `dist/` subdirectories to `path/to/dir`. So there will be no folders inside the destination.

```
copy: {
  files: {
    expand: true,
    dest: 'path/to/dir',
    cwd: 'dist/',
    src: '*/*',
    flatten: true,
    filter: 'isFile'
  }
}
```

Comment: great explaination! +1

Comment: better than the documentation on github, I like examples

Comment: +1 Is there a convention on what the number of stars should mean, for example does `**` always mean files and directories, and `*` just files?

Comment: @Imray From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching): two adjacent `*`s used as a single pattern will match __all files__ and zero or more __directories and subdirectories__. If followed by a `/`, two adjacent `*`s will match __only directories and subdirectories__.

Comment: `**` matches _everything_, whereas `**/` __only__ directories and subdirectories (not files).

Answer (score 2):

Had to use egdy instead curly braces for the files segment (in Coffeescript)...

```
copy: {
  files: [
    cwd: 'path/to/files'
    src: '**/*'
    dest: 'dist/files'
    expand: true
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing with angular yeoman , then this is the better way to copy with grunt.
expand: true is required when using cwd. <%= yeoman.app %> is just the app route ('.').

```
 {
    expand: true,
     cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/data',
     dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/data',
     src: ['**']
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!