# How to use grunt-contrib-copy to copy to root AND change directory structure

Tags: express, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I have an express app with my dev views in `/assets/views`. I figure I need to separate development and production views because in production I'll be editing the HTML when I used grunt-contrib-usemin to concat/uglify scripts.

So here's the problem. My current tree:

```
assets/views
├── 404.html
├── index.html
├── layout.html
├── question_ask.html
└── question_display.html
```

Ideally, I want my production-ready views to live on the same level as assets. Using grunt-contrib-copy, it seems to copy the whole tree. I currently am putting it into `public` since I'm not sure how to set my dest to the root of the project.

```
copy: {
    views: {
        src: ['assets/views/*.html'],
        dest: 'public/'
    }
```

So there are a few questions here:

1. Is it bad practice to have dev views and production views? If so, is there another way of producing a view that has references to concat/uglified scripts?
2. How the heck can I use grunt-contrib-copy to copy to the root of my project? I don't want `assets/views` obviously, I just want a `views/*` folder that has the contents of what's in `assets/views/*`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `flatten` option which will remove the directory structure from the destination path. See my answer here: [Copy all files from directory to another with Grunt.js copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966485/copy-all-files-from-directory-to-another-with-grunt-js-copy/18991208#18991208)

Comment: Nailed it. There is more to it than just flatten though. Also need to 'expand'. Also just realized I could set `dest: './views/'` using the `.` to set the project root.