# Is there any way to copy all the scripts from the bower components to dist/script folder in grunt without minification?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I have generated angular project with `yeomean`.

I have case where I need to show all the scripts used in my angular project after build , But after using the `grunt build` command , grunt minifies all the script files.

Is there any way to copy all the script files from the `bower_components/some_module/some_script.js` to `dist/scripts/some_scripts.js` when I run the `grunt build` command?

There is a way to use the `copy` task of grunt like below:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    src: 'bower_coponents/some_module/some_script.js',
    dest: 'dist/scripts/some_script.js',
  },
}
```

but don't know how to fetch  all the script files from the `app/index.html`.

Comment: If copy works, why not just run the copy task from within the build task? (Also, might wanna look into clean bower installer for copying assets from bower into library folders.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966485/copy-all-files-from-directory-to-another-with-grunt-js-copy this may help you

Answer (score 0):

This peice of code would work coz its Working in my project

```
 copy: {
          main: {
            files: [
              {expand: true, cwd: 'bower_coponents/some_module', src: ['**.js'], dest: 'dist/scripts/'},
           ],
          },
        },
```